# Limit comments per user per post

Tags: comments

I use this code to limit the comments to 1 for registers users and works fine. The problem is that when i click to "go back" button in the browser i can comment again. Is there any effective way to limit the comments?

Thank you!

```
global $current_user, $post;
$args = array( 'user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id' => $post->ID );
$usercomment = get_comments( $args );
if ( 1 <= count( $usercomment ) ) {
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that hook [`pre_comment_approved`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_comment_approved) should be perfect in this case.

Something like this should do the job:

```
function my_pre_comment_approved($approved, $commentdata) {
    // you can return 0, 1 or 'spam'
    if ( $commentdata['user_ID'] ) {
        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $commentdata['user_ID'],
            'post_id' => $commentdata['comment_post_ID']
        );
        $usercomment = get_comments( $args );
        if ( 1 <= count( $usercomment ) )
            return 0;
    }
    return $approved;
}
add_filter('pre_comment_approved', 'my_pre_comment_approved', 99, 2);
```

Your filter should return:

- `0` (i.e. 'false') if the comment should be disapproved
- `1` (i.e. 'true') if the comment should be approved
- `'spam'` if the comment should be marked as spam

Comment: thank you for you answer but this didn't work for me. I also don't want comments go for approvement i need to restrict user for making second comment in the same post.

Comment: Have you tried it? What exactly "didn't work"?

Comment: I put it incide functions.php i left a comment and then i clicked the "go back" button in firefox and then i could comment again...

Comment: as 'urder_ID' do you mean 'user_ID' ?

Comment: Yes, of course it should be `user_ID` (updated unswer)

Comment: That's why i was comfusing. Now works perfect! It would ok if we change the "return 0;" to "wp_die( __('no more comments allowed') );"? Thank you!

Comment: I would leave the `return 0` alone, as the core function that applies the `pre_comment_approved` filter will be expecting `0`, `1`, or `spam` to be returned from your function.

Comment: I have to agree with Pat J. You should be compatible with WordPress core.